# Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time - Error when trying to run iOS tests on a remote appium server - appium log attached

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, appium

I am trying to run `appium` tests on iPhones using a remote `appium` server.
When I run the tests locally they pass but when I just send the remote server's `ip` and try to execute the test I get the following errors in my log:

```
info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.3 (java 1.5)
info: [debug] App is an iOS bundle, will attempt to run as pre-existing
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 87610d1a-b873-46e5-96b0-b54b412f10a0
info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder
info: [debug] Setting Xcode version
info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version
info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout
info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 8.1
info: [debug] Not checking whether simulator is available since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate
info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/com.viber.testing/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/com.viber.testing/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings; assuming it doesn't exist
info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/Desktop-QA/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/usr/local/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}
...o: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/Desktop-QA/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d0f21a5b61bb08af.js
info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/Desktop-QA/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d0f21a5b61bb08af.js
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.1.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.1","deviceName":"none","platformVersion":"8.0.2"}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'none (8.0.2 Simulator)'
info: [debug] Not setting device type since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Checking whether we need to set app preferences
info: [debug] Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Reset not set, not ending sim or cleaning up app state
info: [debug] Not setting locale because we're using a real device
info: [debug] No iOS / app preferences to set
info: [debug] Starting iOS device log capture via deviceconsole
error: Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time
info: [debug] Error: Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time
at null.onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/nodemodules/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios-log.js:139:10)
at Timer.listOnTimeout as ontimeout
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time)","origValue":"Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 11148.632 ms - 234
```

I tried newer devices ,cleaning the logs from the device and restarting it but all of these didn't help.

Any help will be more then welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temporary solution for me was to run appium from source,replacing Deviceconsole with devicesyslog (the previous one) and now it works and i can get the logs from the device even when i am running on a remote appium with a remote device